# Java Swing - How to detect doubleclick on tab header in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

Is there any way I can detect doubleclick on tab header in JTabbedPane ?

I do not mean ChangeEvent..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `MouseListener` to the tabbed pane.

Then you can determine which tab was double clicked by using something like:

```
TappedPaneUI ui = tabbedPane.getUI();
int tab = ui.tabForCordinate(...);

if (tab = ??? and doubleClick)
    // do something
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found solution few seconds after posting this:

```
jTabbedPane1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
             if (evt.getClickCount()==2 && jTabbedPane1.indexAtLocation(evt.getX(), evt.getY())==3) {
                 //deteced doubleclick on tab with index 3
             }
        }
    });
```

Comment: (1+) good one. I thought there was a JTabbedPane method to get the information. I couldn't find it when I looked. Hopefully, I'll remember this for the next time.